# React-admin: Multi-line notification messages

Tags: notifications, message, react-admin

How could i make react-admin to show a multi-line notification / error message on the snackbar?

Having the following dataProvider:

```js
export default (type, resource, params) => {
    throw new Error(`
     Message line 1.
     Message line 2.
     Message line 3.
    `);
};
```

That shows a single line message when loading a List component:

[error notification screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaZiO.gif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022:**

Since version 4 of react-admin, you can tell the `useNotify` hook, to use a multi line message passing the `multiLine` prop: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useNotify.html#multiline.

End of UPDATE.

Ok, with the help of the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#notifications) I manage to do what I wanted.
Defining a custom Layout component to be used by the App component and passing it a custom Notification component.

```js
// ./MyLayout.js
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'react-admin';
import MyNotification from "../MyNotification";

    
const CustomLayout = props => (
    <Layout {...props} notification={MyNotification} />
);

export default CustomLayout;
```

Then I pass a custom CSS class to the Notification component.

```js
// ./MyNotification.js
import React from 'react';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {Notification} from 'react-admin';

// Allow multi-line messages to be displayed
const cssMsg = {
    snackbarContent: {
        whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'
    }
};

const MyNotification = withStyles(cssMsg)(({classes, ...props}) => (
    <Notification {...props} className={classes.snackbarContent}/>
));

export default MyNotification;
```

[error notification screenshot multi-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54W7m.gif)